# Simple & secure dekstop application platform for making HTTP requests with a GUI

Tags: cross-platform, http

I'd like to make a desktop application that will perform HTTP requests and data analysis from these requests, with user interaction. It will be GUI based.

I also need it to be secure, in that the source code can't easily be derived. This requirement alone seems to rule out popular choices like appJS and TideKit.

I've had a look at Visual C++, but the initial setup and code seems overly complex for a project this simple. I'm natively a JS developer.

I'd like some recommendations on what platform to use in developing this application.